# Why is my function returning "newLine.unshift(startN) is not a function"

Tags: javascript, function, recursion

I have been trying to write a recursive function to get a range of numbers, but I am getting an error saying `'newLine. unshift(startN) is not a function'`.

**Following is the code:**

```
function rangeOfNumbers(startN, endN) {
  if (startN - endN === 0) {
    return "The starting number will always be less than or equal to the ending number";
  } else {
    const newLine = rangeOfNumbers(startN + 1, endN);
    newLine.unshift(startN);
    return newLine;
  }
}

console.log(rangeOfNumbers(1, 7));
```

Can someone please help me to find the reason for getting the error mentioned?

Comment: I can't read that at all, but I don't see `rangeOfNumbers` returning anything except the error condition, so it's not clear what you're expecting.

Comment: unshift is a method that is applied to an array. e.g. arr = [1, 2, 3]. arr.unshift(4, 5). You cannot write unshit to your rangeOfNumber function. 

Please tell what is the expected result that you want

Comment: Oh, I think there is a `return` in there, but I don't see where it's initialized to anything other than in the error condition.

Answer (score 0):

rangeOfNumbers(1, 7)  / **newLine** = rangeOfNumbers(2, 7)
rangeOfNumbers(2, 7)  / **newLine** = rangeOfNumbers(3, 7)
...
rangeOfNumbers(7, 7)  / **newLine** = "The starting number will always be ..."

typeof **newLine** = String
newLine.unshift() >> undefined // unshift isn't available JS Strings